# Static IP on FEDORA12 from Virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ubuntu-9.04, fedora-12, static-ip

I'm trying to get my FEDORA12 to have an STATIC IP - inside VirtualBox - inside Ubuntu

Let me rephrase that. I have an Ubuntu 9.04 system with VirtualBox and a FEDORA12 VM.  I would like to use a static IP on the Fedora VM (amahi needs it), but I'm getting stuck... 
I'm using NAT (if that's any help)

I tried a few tutorials, but no go.

I'm kind of new to the *nix world but I'm old school on M$

---

### Screenshots:

**UBUNTU 9.04** (host that has the VM)

[image]

**FEDORA**

[image]

[image]

---

### INFO:

**GUEST WITH STATIC:**

*IFCONFIG:*

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:35:CC:DE  
          inet addr:192.168.1.55  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe35:ccde/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2764 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:574 (574.0 b)  TX bytes:127121 (124.1 KiB)
          Interrupt:11 Base address:0xc020 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1856 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1856 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:181587 (177.3 KiB)  TX bytes:181587 (177.3 KiB)
```

*NETSTAT -NR:*

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0
```

**GUEST WITH DHCP:**

*IFCONFIG:*

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:35:CC:DE  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe35:ccde/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:105 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2966 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:49787 (48.6 KiB)  TX bytes:149969 (146.4 KiB)
          Interrupt:11 Base address:0xc020 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1903 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1903 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:185931 (181.5 KiB)  TX bytes:185931 (181.5 KiB)
```

*NETSTAT -NR:*

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0
```

PS.: I'm still trying to workout the sudoer file to be able to exec the iptables command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your IP address to be on the same subnet as the virtual NAT router.  As you can see from when you use DHCP on the guest the subnet is `10.0.2.0/255.255.255.0`, so, when you are setting a static IP address it needs to be in the `10.0.2.x` range.  Try setting it to something like `10.0.2.150`.  If possible, look in the VirtualBox settings to find the range of IPs the DHCP server will assign so you don't use one of those.  Once your on the same subnet, it should work just fine.  Just to summarize, here are your settings:

```
IP: 10.0.2.150
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 10.0.2.2
```